# Cannot see files with "ls" when i copy paste files or download with rightclick save as

Tags: ls

I am new to Linux-like environment. Currently, using Ubuntu on Windows.
When i download a file by rightclick and save as or copy/paste a file to a folder, I cannot see them or access them using "ls". But if download using wget, the file appears....
Could someone explained please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to comment so I am using the answer:

- Are the files visible in your file explorer (e.g. nautilus)?
- Have you tried `ls -la`?

Using `wget`, you are defining in your terminal where to store the files.
Using the contextmenu and then the "*save as*"-button, kind of means leaving that context. I am sure the files are stored somewhere else - just not in the same folder as it does, when you use `wget`.

Try to open the directory from your browser from you downloads-list and then open the terminal from the file explorer. This usually is possible by right clicking and choosing "*Open Terminal here*".